# Android NSD. Have errors when trying to resolve

Tags: java, android, nsd

I'm making android quiz with local network multiplayer where host should send message to all clients. I'm using [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/NsdChat/src/com/example/android/nsdchat) sample of NsdChat.
But when I try to reslove service I get this errors.

```
E/NsdServiceInfo: While parsing txt records (pos = 1): Zero sized txt record
E/NsdHelper: Resolve Succeeded. name: NsdChatHost, type: ._http._tcp, host: /"myIP", port: "myPort", txtRecord: 
E/NsdService: Unique id with no client mapping: 71
E/NsdService: Unhandled { when=-4ms what=393242 obj=com.android.server.NsdService$NativeEvent@157683e target=com.android.internal.util.StateMachine$SmHandler }
```

It's my resolve listener.

```
public void initializeResolveListener() {
        mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve failed" + errorCode);
            }
            @Override
            public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);
                if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Same IP.");
                    return;
                }
                mService = serviceInfo;
            }
        };
    }
```